# passing button id in android

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
private Button.OnClickListener gotologinpage3 = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Intent ii = new Intent(v.getContext(), login_profile.class);
            startActivityForResult(ii,0);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
};
```

Can I pass button id to function makenewProfile from class login_profile?

Comment: You have a class that's called `login_class`? You should use camel-case for classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add `extras`:

```
Intent ii = new Intent(v.getContext(), login_profile.class);
ii.putExtra("id", myId);

startActivityForResult(ii, 0);
```

And pick them up like so:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id = extras.getInt("id");
```

Comment: one more question sir, i can call function and pass same value in anther class using same above code?i mean to say that i hava a functin name "makeNewProfile" in class login_profile and i want to call this function as well as pass same value.

Comment: i'd say the easiest way to do that, would be to add another extra, such as `ii.putExtra("makeNewProfile", true);` and fetch it in `login_profile`: `if(extras.getBoolean("makeNewProfile")) { makeNewProfile(); }`

Comment: Hey Bibek, just as a heads-up, you should mark answers as accepted (the little checkmark on the left) if they answer you question. That helps people build reputation and rewards them for spending time answering your questions.